# How to create Log File on hourly basis in Zend Framework 1.1

Tags: php, apache, zend-framework, logging, logfile

I have created log file on day basis but on day basis content have huge amount of data and difficult to download and open so i want to create on hour basis

Below the content of log4phpconfig.xml

Path :library\log4php\log4phpconfig.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration xmlns="http://logging.apache.org/log4php/">
    <appender name="default" class="LoggerAppenderDailyFile">
        <layout class="LoggerLayoutPattern">
            <param name="conversionPattern" value="%d{Y-m-d H:i:s} %c %-5p %F %L %m%n" />
        </layout>
        <layout class="LoggerLayoutSimple" />
        <param name="file" value="/var/www/html/demoproject/webtoollogs/webtoollog-%s.log" />
        <param name="datePattern" value="Y-m-d" />
    </appender>
    <root>
        <appender_ref ref="default" />
    </root>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, In this case, a new file will be created each second.

```
<param name="datePattern" value="Y-m-d.H.i.s" />
```

In this case, a new file will be created each hour.

```
<param name="datePattern" value="Y-m-d.H" />
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration xmlns="http://logging.apache.org/log4php/">
    <appender name="default" class="LoggerAppenderDailyFile">
        <layout class="LoggerLayoutPattern">
            <param name="conversionPattern" value="%d{Y-m-d H:i:s} %c %-5p %F %L %m%n" />
        </layout>
        <layout class="LoggerLayoutSimple" />
        <param name="file" value="/var/www/html/demoproject/webtoollogs/webtoollog-%s.log" />
        <param name="datePattern" value="Y-m-d.H" />
    </appender>
    <root>
        <appender_ref ref="default" />
    </root>
</configuration>
```